# What will happen to Qatar flights from Doha if there is an airspace closure?

Tags: air-travel, event-based-effects, qatar-airways, qatar

A [diplomatic argument between Qatar and its neighbors](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-40168856) is currently threatening Qatar Airways operations:

> Several countries have cut ties with Qatar, accusing it of supporting terrorism in the Gulf region.
>
> Neighbours including Saudi Arabia and the United Arab Emirates (UAE) have closed their airspace to Qatari planes.

I have a flight going to Pisa via Doha with Qatar Airways. If it's banned from using the Bahrain, UAE, and Saudi airspaces, then what will be its route?

Should I be worried about my flight?

Comment: My next Qatar Airways flight to Europe is on Thursday. Personally, I do not expect any problems.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At the moment, they can still 'escape' via Iran, like this picture from FlightRadar24 shows:

[image]

and from there to Turkey and Europe. As [Alexander](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94678/what-will-happen-to-qatar-flights-from-doha-if-there-is-an-airspace-closure/94680?noredirect=1#comment227512_94680) notes, this is because they can still use the Bahrain airspace; Bahrain committed to the [IASTA](https://www.icao.int/secretariat/legal/List%20of%20Parties/Transit_EN.pdf) which forbids them to close the airspace to other members, like Qatar.

More information can be found [here](https://blog.flightradar24.com/blog/flight-ban-for-qatar-flights-in-uae-saudi-arabia-bahrain-and-egypt/).

In any case, you should definitely pay attention to any information regarding your flight, and you can expect it to take a little longer because of the detour.

Comment: I am not sure your answer is correct. [Right now Bahrain has not closed its airspace to Qatar, but when it does, Qatar Airways may be effectively locked out.](http://www.businessinsider.de/qatar-airways-banned-from-crucial-airspace-2017-6?r=US&IR=T)

Comment: Ah, that seems to be correct, but it isn't really clear from the picture above, which shows Bahrain and Qatar as one airspace region. Still: *While the countries are free to refuse landing rights, it is unclear if Bahrain and the UAE can legally ban Qatar Airways from its airspace. As signatories to the International Air Services Transit Agreement, Bahrain the UAE can't legally shut off its airspace to fellow signatory Qatar.*

Comment: Not legally, but illegally. Is there a court Qatar could drag them to?

Comment: If they're illegally closing it, could Qatar Airways *illegally* use the closed airspace?

Comment: That depends on whether they're willing to take the risk of being shot down.

Comment: @Alexander I doubt any there is anything an international Court which can enforce this. Airspace is a property of the country and no country can be forced to do anything. Many countries block Israel and vice versa. They just avoid the airspace and seek alternate route. That's all Qatar can do too.

Comment: @Glordindel The rulers of Bahrain and the UAE are absolute monarchs who have the power to change what is legal at the stroke of a pen. They aren't going to shoot down a QR passenger flight. But QR isn't going to infringe airspace declared closed to them by the sovereign rulers of the airspace, being protected only by a piece of paper. Let's deal with practicalities.

Comment: Does Bahrain actually own that airspace? The maps that are circulating around seem to be of FIRs (which is why some of them, including this one, show nothing for Qatar - others show the Doha TMA carved out of it), not territorial airspace. How does territorial airspace actually work over international waters? (the area in question is in Qatar's EEZ)

Comment: @PeterTaylor- the issue is that Bahrain provides ATC in international airspace to the north of Qatar. Indeed, Bahrain is in charge of ATC over Qatar itself, above a certain altitude. But I don't think Bahrain is going to start shooting down civilian airliners in international or Qatari airspace over this, the most they can do is block their actual territorial airspace which is far less extensive than their FIR where they provide ATC services. As Bahrain itself is tiny, I don't believe that *their* blocking their own airspace has much effect. The others, particularly Saudi Arabia, matters more.

Comment: @MaxPayne- sovereign airspace is a property of the country, yes, but what the map he linked shows is FIRs which cover who provides ATC in a particular region and can extend into international airspace or indeed other countries' airspace. A country cannot block access to its FIR on sovereign grounds.

Comment: @Alexander I believe that article confuses FIRs (who runs ATC in a given region) and sovereign airspace. They are not the same thing. Much of what is shown as the Bahrain FIR in that map is international airspace and they can't forbid Qatar from flying through it. Indeed Bahrain even controls ATC *above Qatar* although that is obviously Qatari airspace.

Answer (score 13):

Based on the [FlightAware site](https://flightaware.com/live/fleet/QTR), many flights are unaffected, some (mostly flights to south Europe) will have to fly longer.

Generally:

1. Flights to east and north Europe fly over Iran and Turkey, and are unaffected.
2. Flights to south Europe fly over Saudi Arabia and Egypt, which have blocked their airspace. They'll have to take a longer path, over Iran and Turkey.
3. Flights to east Asia fly over the Persian Gulf and Iran and are unaffected.
4. Flights to Africa fly over Saudi Arabia. They'll have to take a longer path, around the Arabian peninsula.
5. Flights to Jordan fly over Saudi Arabia. They now take a longer path over Iraq (which is normally avoided by all carriers).

Comment: Flights to Africa can overfly Oman (at least so far), so they don't have to avoid the *entire* Arabian Peninsula.  See, for example, [Qatar Airlines Flight 1335 from Doha to Nairobi on 2017-06-06.](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/QTR1335/history/20170606/0600Z/OTHH/HKJK)

Comment: How large of an impact are #2 and 4?   I'm wondering mostly in terms of is this just an increased fuel/etc cost problem; or are they going to have to shuffle routes around due to needing longer ranged aircraft on some routes and/or not being able to get as many flights/day from a single plane?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Oman is a reliable neutral party in the region. I would not expect them to take sides in this.

Comment: Concerning #5:  Apparently they are overflying Iraq.  [Qatar Airways Flight 400, Doha–Amman, 2017-06-06.](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/QTR400/history/20170606/1355Z/OTHH/OJAI)